# Добавление кода в Ifame

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Возможно ли добавить код в iframe?

Мне нужно добавить в `<head></head>` внешний CSS.
Возможно ли это реализовать при помощи JS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Если на разных доменах, то только с помощью JS нет**. (Same-origin policy или Правило ограничения домена)

Ограничение «**одного источника**» запрещает окнам и фреймам с разных источников вызывать методы друг друга и читать данные друг из друга.

При этом «из одного источника» означает «**совпадают протокол, домен и порт**».

Если на одном домене, то обычным JS вот так:

```
var cssLink = document.createElement("link") 
cssLink.href = "style.css"; 
cssLink.rel = "stylesheet"; 
cssLink.type = "text/css"; 
frames['nameOfElementIframe'].document.body.appendChild(cssLink);
```