# Возможно ли заменить стили в iframe?

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, telegram

Есть на сайте чат с телеграмом **Replain**. [Пример](http://bez-krizisa.ru/stroyka_saita/kak-ustanovit-chat-telegram-na-sajt-wordpress-obratnaya-svyaz-online-u-vas-pod-rukoj.html)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подгрузка стилей идет через `iframe`. Возможно ли заменить иконку телеграмма на лого своего сайта? Через стили не прокатывает..

```
#__replain_widget #__replain_widget_iframe .ctc__show {
    background-color: transparent!important;
}
    #__replain_widget #__replain_widget_iframe .ctc__show__img {
        background-image: url(images/call_logo.png)!important;
    }
```

Comment: за что минус-то?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет.

> **Если на разных доменах, то только с помощью JS нет**. (Same-origin policy или Правило > ограничения домена)
>
> Ограничение «**одного источника**» запрещает окнам и фреймам с разных источников вызывать методы друг друга и читать данные друг из друга.
>
> При этом «из одного источника» означает «**совпадают протокол, домен и порт**».
>
> Если на одном домене, то обычным JS вот так:
>
> ```
> var cssLink = document.createElement("link") 
> cssLink.href = "style.css"; 
> cssLink.rel = "stylesheet"; 
> cssLink.type = "text/css"; 
> frames['nameOfElementIframe'].document.body.appendChild(cssLink);
> ```

Источник: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/571570/221218