# Как вывести в iframe 1 конкретный блок и принудительно кастомизировать?

Tags: javascript, jquery

1) Как можно вывести конкретный блок в iframe? 
А именно середину из чата в песочнице https://jsfiddle.net/Mesuti/z3tm6jk9/ 
На картинке отметил https://yadi.sk/i/mqfJ0QHGpA_EDA 
2) Как, например сменить фон у чата на своей стороне? 
Этот скрипт вывода блока с ID="hu-messenger" не помогает

```
$('#chat-bot').load('https://landbot.io/u/H-129986-FRFEKEF4Q5E6AQ73/index.html#hu-messenger');
```

Comment: В данном примере - никак. [Подробнее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/571570/221218)

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку данный chatbot не работает в iframe, вы можете делать все, что хотите. Скрыть любые блоки и кастомизоровать, как хотите.

```js
$('#chat-bot').load('https://landbot.io/u/H-129986-FRFEKEF4Q5E6AQ73/index.html');

//hide header and footer in 8 seconds
setTimeout(() => {
  $('#hu-footer,#hu-header').hide();
}, 8000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chat-bot"></div>
```